# Run macro on row most recently added

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using a macro to generate an Outlook template based on data that has been entered into a workbook.

In the workbook I have 100 rows of data and 7 sheets.

I need to run the macro (on click of a button) on the most recent row's data and generate the template.

My rows contain time data (example 13:37, next row 14:02 etc) so I think that could be a good way to identify the latest row.

I'm using this code. I'm selecting the row using **A203:G203**

```
Sub NonConformanceGenerator()

    ActiveSheet.Range("A203:G203").Select

    Const HEADER_ROW As Long = 202 '<< the row with column headers
    Const NUM_COLS As Long = 7   '<< how many columns of data

    Const olMailItem = 0
    Const olFolderInbox = 6

    Dim ol As Object, fldr, ns, msg
    Dim html As String, c As Range, colReq As Long, hdr As Range
    Dim rw As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set ol = GetObject(, "outlook.application")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If ol Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ol = CreateObject("outlook.application")
        Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Set fldr = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
        fldr.display
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If

    If ol Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Couldn't start Outlook to compose mail!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set msg = ol.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    Set rw = Selection.Cells(1).EntireRow

    msg.Subject = ""

    html = "<style type='text/css'>"
    html = html & "body, p {font:11pt calibri;padding:40px;}"
    html = html & "table {border-collapse:collapse}"
    html = html & "td {border:1px solid #000;padding:8px;}"
    html = html & "</style>"

    html = html & "<p>Hello,</p>"
    html = html & "<table>"

For Each c In rw.Cells(1).Resize(1, NUM_COLS).Cells

    If c.Column <> 0 Then '<<< This removes the 4th column if you type number 4 after the <> symbols

        Set hdr = rw.Parent.Cells(HEADER_ROW, c.Column) '<< get the header text for this cell

        html = html & "<tr><td style='background-color:#FFF;width:200px;'>" & _
          hdr.Value & _
          "</td><td style='width:400px;'>" & Trim(c.Value) & "</td></tr>"

        End If 'we want this cell

    Next c   

    html = html & "</table>"

    msg.HTMLBody = html
    msg.display

    ActiveSheet.Range("A15").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need to select a range in the code - just select any cell on the row using the mouse (or keyboard) and run the macro (maybe add a button on the sheet to trigger it) - it will pick up the "active" row automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Is the newest row always at the bottom of the spreadsheet? If so, you can use `Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` to return the last row with data in Column "A" for instance.

You could do something like this for use in your example.

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Range("A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Resize(1, 7).Select
End With
```